# App crashes When using camera

Tags: android, android-camera, filepath, android-cursor

I am new on Android and have been struggling with this for days now, I have my app and a button that opens the camera, when I take a picture using the camera and storing it in a folder on the device after that I have a button to that send this picture to a DB but the app crashes, I had achieved the same selecting a picture from gallery without problems. I had read about what could cause this problem and I had posted already about this, but still, can't figure it out what's wrong. I think I might have some ideas of why this is happening but don't know how to solve it.

So I don't know if the reason the app crashes on that line, is because the picture that the cursor is making reference is not in that folder and it's on the one created to store the picture or when receiving the file path this is null. I really hope someone can help me.

This is the code:

```
 botonflotante.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            filePath = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
            //filePath = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filePath);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), (filePath));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, filePath));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;

 private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(   //getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Vallarta en tus manos Nougat");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("Vallarta en tus manos", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

   public class CargarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        ////////////////-------------
        String correo = campo_correo.getText().toString().trim();
        String nombre = campo_nombre.getText().toString().trim();
        String apellido= campo_apellido.getText().toString().trim();
        String telefono= campo_telefono.getText().toString().trim();
        String categoria= customspinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String titulo = campo_titulo.getText().toString().trim();
        String descripcion = campo_descripcion.getText().toString().trim();
        String latitud = Double.toString(latitudeeeee);
        String longitud = Double.toString(longitudeeee);

        String s = (campo_publico.isChecked() ? "1" : "0");
        String r = (campo_terminos.isChecked() ? "1" : "0");

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name",correo) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("nombre",nombre)
                    .addParameter("apellido",apellido)
                    .addParameter("telefono", telefono)
                    .addParameter("categoria", categoria)
                    .addParameter("titulo", titulo)
                    .addParameter("descripcion", descripcion)
                    .addParameter("publico", s)
                    .addParameter("terminos", r)
                    .addParameter("latitud",latitud)
                    .addParameter("longitud",longitud)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
```

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-29 22:46:49.200 11628-11628/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC.getPath(TerminosYC.java:529)
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC$1.onClick(TerminosYC.java:362)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: First thing first - check for nulls. You aren't checking cursor for null at all.

Comment: You mean to add like a condition or something in case cursor is null? @Varundroid

Comment: Check if you have the following permission in your manifest - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Yes, you should always check for nulls. It's a good practice.

Comment: Yes i do. @Varundroid

Comment: Ok im goin to add a condition to see if cursor is null. @Varundroid

Comment: Check this `TerminosYC.getPath(TerminosYC.java:529)`. In my guess, your method asked for `Uri` as a parameter, but you didn't provide it when you call this method out `String getPath(Uri uri)`

Comment: Yes it does. It ask for uri as a parameter. and it works when i attach a picture from gallery @Jacky. So i don't know what might be wrong.

Comment: I don't see in your code where did you call this method out, can you post it? `return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");` this `getPath()` is from `File` class right

Comment: Sure, done @Jacky i edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The very first step to move with is to add code for runtime permission to enable access for external storage and camera and also add your permission to access hardware(Camera). You can then proceed next with camera intent code.

Code for hardware access

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
```

Code ti start camera intent

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
```

Recieve the Image on ActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

if you are saving and managing the files in the external storage then do not forget to add the file provider to you manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

It will be your file paths XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

To save the image in gallery
private void galleryAddPic() {

```
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with the last part about the provider?

Comment: I added the permissions before the picture was stored in a folder the app worked fine using gallery and camera, but the app usng the camera didn't work on Nougat devices so that's why i added the part of storing in a folder but now i got that issue that i cant solve. :(

Comment: to save the images and manage with files android has now added a provider to use to manage with the files. i have edited my answer you can check for same.

Comment: Right now i am able to take a picture, store the picture in a folder but not to send it to the DB. Do i need to add the provider part?

Comment: If you are able to acccess the pic from storage to a imageview than you dont need the same. May be there can be any issue in your code to upload pic on server.

Comment: Yes i am able to see the picture on the imageview, and on the device gallery but like i said before i worked when i didnt store the picture in a folder and i was able to send the picture and store it in a DB. but now using this code it doesn't work